# How to iterate and add each "many" in a one-to-many class

Tags: java, grails

I have two classes. The OrderSlip class has a one-to-many relationship with orderedItemDescription.

```
class OrderSlip {   
    String employeeID
    int serving
    int tableNumber

    static hasMany = [orderedItemDescription: OrderedItemDescription]
}

class OrderedItemDescription {

    MenuItem menuItem
    MenuItemProgressStatus progress//progress
    String descriptionOfOrder
    int quantity = 1

    static belongsTo = OrderSlip
}
```

Now my problem is how do i iterate `orderedItemDescription` so that when i update my orderSlip i can add many orderedItemDescriptions along with its properties.

```
def updateOrderSlip(Long id) {
    User currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
    def orderSlipInstance = Table.get(id)

    //other codes for orderedItemDescription here
    orderSlipInstance.employeeID = currentUser.username
    orderSlipInstance.serving= Integer.parseInt(params.serving)
    orderSlipInstance.tableNumber= params.tableNumber
    render(action:'server')
}
```

Im doing something like this in my gsp. im only adding data to the DOM with the add buttons. Then for the send order im hoping i can update it like the problem since im also adding many g:hiddenField for each orderedItemDescription in my summary

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be persisting each new instance `OrderedItemDescription` somehow.

You can store it immediately in the DB upon click on `add`-button with the `status` flag set to `incomplete`. When you save the whole order, you must change the `incomplete` to `complete`.

Another option would be to keep the items in the http session. Upon `send order` you iterate through the in-session items and persist them all along with the order instance.

Both ways have advantages and drawbacks, but they both are useful.

Comment: Aren't i already keeping the items in http session since i can just assign some data attributes using js then use them on something. i dont know how to persist the `OrderedItemDescription` though. btw what's the  `status` flag?

Comment: If you explicitly assign add you items to the session, like `session.items = items`, then they are. Otherwise they are present only in your browser's DOM model.

`status` flag is a new property you would add to `OrderedItemDescription` should you want implement the "persist immediately" approach. The saving is standard `new OrderedItemDescription( order:order, user:user, ... ).save()`

Comment: Ok. maybe i will just get the OrderItemDescription using params. Then, how do i iterate all the `orderItemDescription` while saving each of them with new `OrderedItemDescription(....)` . After that i will assign the result to `orderSlipInstance.OrderedItemDescription = result`. All of this is still under the `updateOrderSlip`

Comment: Ah. there will be no need for `orderSlipInstance.OrderedItemDescription = result` since i can assign each iteration's belongTo. Now the problem is how do i iterate them